# How to get an alert while downloading or installing app into device or simulator

Tags: iphone, app-store

How can I alert a user while installing an app or downloading it from app store? If anyone knows please help me. For example "http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/comics/id323397665?mt=8" when I try to download this it is giving me some alert related to age limit. For generating these types of alert do I need to code it in my application or are there any specific settings  while uploading the app into app store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control these kind of alerts. The alerts you mention are generated by Apple and effected by the limitation your application has according to the details you provided (and Apple approved) when you upload you app to the store for the first time.